# grep last 2 minutes of log?

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have log file that is generated in below format.
 I want to grep the log every 2 minutes and check for error
 using shell script how Can I get this?
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[12:17:02.1274]
[12:18:01.1976]
[12:18:01.2151]
[12:18:01.2152]
[12:18:01.4607]
[12:18:02.6306]
[12:18:03.7299]
[12:18:04.0307]
[12:18:04.1388]
[12:18:04.2068]
[12:18:06.4002]
[12:18:07.5805]
[12:19:01.8559]
[12:19:08.9950]
[12:19:09.2851]
[12:19:10.4704]
[12:19:12.8167]
[12:20:01.8968]
[12:20:01.9206]
[12:20:01.9206]
[12:20:02.1707]
[12:20:02.3064]
[12:20:05.4461]
[12:20:13.7205]
[12:20:14.0807]
[12:20:14.2360]
[12:20:17.3764]
[12:21:01.2299]
[12:21:10.4769]
[12:21:18.8085]
[12:21:19.1106]
[12:21:19.2456]
[12:21:22.3663]
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want to check if any errors happened *during the last 2 minutes*? That is, if the time now is 12:21:22, you want to check for errors logged since 12:19?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sleep](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/) function.

Try e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo start
sleep 2
echo end
```

Which will wait 2 seconds between the two echo commands.

---

Your complete script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash    
while [ 1 ]; do
        sleep 2m
        if grep -qvE "^\[[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\]" logfile.dat
        then
                echo "ERROR"
        else
                echo "Everything is fine..."
        fi
done
```

The **while-loop** is always running because `1` is `true`. In this infinite loop each two minutes (`2m`) the check is done.

**edit**

I updated the code so that the data structure you were given is parsed. I use `grep` with

- `-E` to enable the usage of regex
- `-v` to match only the inverse (meaning that it searches for your structure and is actually grepping if this pattern **isn't** matching)
- `-q` to use quiet mode and exit immediately if a match is found

If your **logfile.dat** is not exactly of the style you were giving, grep is matching and **ERROR** is written to `STDOUT` which typically is your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "$ s/\[\([0-9.:]*\)\].*/\1/p" | read Marker
while [ 1 ]
 do
   sleep 120
   sed -n "$ s/\[\([0-9.:]*\)\].*/\1/p" | read NewMarker
   sed -n "/${Marker/,/${NewMarker}/ p"
   Marker="${NewMarker}"
 done
```

it just print Twice the marker value (1 at last cylcle as last line) and one at current cycle as 1s line. It can be modified by replacing `p` with `/${Marker}/ !p`.

May not work if log is never close (if no EOF occur) because sed wait until that without explicit exit.