# Parsing Log Files With grep for Every 5 minutes interval

Tags: java, shell, grep

I am using trilead ssh2  to make ssh connection and parse the log files for every 5 minutes before.

I am using this syntax:-

```
grep '29/Jan/2018:[0-0][6-6]:[1-2][6-1]' /root/nohup.out>/tmp/nohup.txt
```

Basicaly I am building an android app which will parse log file for every 5 minutes interval  and store it into /tmp/nohup.txt and will download and  parse it to find the exceptions and show user those exception notification etc.

```
String  parsingCommand="grep"+" ' "+day2+"/"+month2+"/"+year2+":"+"["+hour2/10+"-"+hour1/10+"]"+"["+hour2%10+"-"+hour1%10+"]"+":"+"["+minute2/10+"-"+minute1/10+"]"+"["+minute2%10+"-"+minute1%10+"]"+" ' "+"/root/nohup.out"+">"+"/tmp/nohup.txt";
```

Here minute1 = current minute fetched from server &  minute2= minutes reduced by 5 minutes

```
grep '29/Jan/2018:[0-0][6-6]:[1-2][6-1]' /root/nohup.out>/tmp/nohup.txt
```

Here in this case minutes interval is 16-21.

I think i am not using proper regular expression .Because

```
grep '29/Jan/2018:[0-0][6-6]:[1-2][1-6]' /root/nohup.out>/tmp/nohup.txt
```

Its working.

Any help would be appreciated.
Although so many answer are already  here in stackoverflow:-

[grep last 2 minutes of log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023805/grep-last-2-minutes-of-log)

https://superuser.com/questions/439688/how-to-grep-a-log-file-within-a-specific-time-period

Comment: why to use sed instead of grep. try this sed -n '/2018-01-29 08:00:00/,/2018-01-29 08:02:00/p' example.log to get last 2 min logs. Since your using it in Android you can do newDate() and subract 5 min from it pass it to the sed command with param1 as earlier date and param2 current date. You can use formatter to format it according to the pattern your application is using in logs. Note* Always use date.getTime() when doing any manipulation  or formatting of time.

Comment: I also tried with sed but log file doesnot contain /2018-01-29 08:00:00 date    sed will now show data if sed -n '/2018-01-29 08:00:00/,/2018-01-29 08:02:00/p'  .  In case of sed  it seems to  have first field i.e 2018-01-29 08:00:00 mandatory and must be present in log file  and it exclueds last field  . In my case first field may or may not be present .

Answer (score 2):

I would use non capturing groups and "or":

```
egrep '29/Jan/2018:(?:(?:06:16)|(?:06:17)|(?:06:18)|(?:06:19)|(?:06:20)|(?:06:21))' /root/nohup.out>/tmp/nohup.out
```

Your current solution would also get entries from 06:11 and on the other hand miss entries from 06:20.

To include the date in the groups would even be better. Otherwise you could get problems at midnight:

```
egrep '(?:28/Jan/2018:23:59)|(?:29/Jan/2018:00:00)|(?:29/Jan/2018:00:01)|(?:29/Jan/2018:00:02)|(?:29/Jan/2018:00:03)' ...
```

You can accomplish that by using a StringBuilder:

```
public String getGrepCommand(final Date start) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();

    cal.setTime(start);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        bld.append("|(?:");
        bld.append(String.format("%1$td/%1$tb/%1%tY:%1$tH:%1$tM", cal.getTime()));
        bld.append(")");
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    }

    if (bld.length() > 0) { // should be ;)
        bld.delete(1, 1);
    }

    return bld.toString();

}
```

Comment: I have used this  egrep '(?:22/Jan/2018:07:39)|(?:22/Jan/2018:07:40)|(?:22/Jan/2018:07:41)|(?:22/Jan/2018:07:42)|(?:22/Jan/2018:07:43)' nohup.out  and it is not showing data. I am attaching here the link of log file on which i am checking it .       Please check on  this  file :  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jYkf-bMtphkTO-CHqOfpinx-OCbwyU-r

Comment: you are using '/' operator without escaping the character . try (?:23\/Jan\/2018:06:15)|(?:23\/Jan\/2018:06:16).

Comment: Thanks - of course you are right. Typing too fast ;)

Answer (score 1):

for the below input:

```
  2018-01-29 08:00:30,393  
  2018-01-29 08:02:00,003   
  2018-01-29 08:03:00,210 
  2018-01-29 08:01:00,401  
  2018-01-29 08:01:00,401  
  2018-01-29 08:05:00,401   
  2018-01-29 08:16:00,002
  2018-01-29 08:17:00,002
  2018-01-29 08:18:00,002
  2018-01-29 08:19:00,002
  2018-01-29 08:20:00,002
  2018-01-29 08:21:00,002
```

if you try running this regex:

```
  2018-01-29 08:(0[0-4]|1[6-9]|2[0-1])
```

you will see a perfect match for 5 min. You will have to use the or operator for multi pattern matching.The way you re building the regex , you will have to do a lot of calculations. To save so much effort the solution provided by Daniel is proper as per your need.

Comment: I was missing -E in grep !!!what a silly mistake :). grep -E "22/Jan/2018:06:(4[6-9]|5[0-1])" nohup.out >/home/himanshu/Desktop/nohup.txt     .It is now displaying the date 06  :46- 51 minutes.   Log file url:=      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jYkf-bMtphkTO-CHqOfpinx-OCbwyU-r/view